# How to check for ID exists or not in database table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenario , where i run a cron and pull data from remote database and insert into local database.

I have a unique key defined on my column. From the Data of remote database, i need to Bypass records which exists from local system, and insert the records which are new.

I cannot write a select query and check for 200 records every time. Please suggest me if any dynamic approach

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code that is now doing the copying.

Comment: `insert ignore` is designed for this. think about it: run 200 insert queries with "ignore", which skips inserting any records that'd cause a duplicate, or having to run 200 selects and then some number of inserts, turning your 200 insert queries into 200+n queries? plus select-then-possible-insert being racy and possibly causing problems if someone inserts a "dupe" behind your back?

Comment: Thanks Marc... I think this will work for me.

Comment: @MarcB provides words of wisdom - fewer queries is usually better (with few exceptions - this isn't one of them though). It should be noted that if you want more advanced behaviour, look into `insert .. on duplicate key update` - this could be useful for, say, `.. on duplicate key update lastchecked = now()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INSERT IGNORE` will ignore all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some benchmark test on INSERT IGNORE.
  It would be just as or more efficient to DELETE the LOCAL table and not use IGNORE.

**Total time:  With and Empty `LOCAL` Table**
**0.4357 - 0.4506 sec**

```
INSERT INTO `LOCAL` SELECT * FROM `REMOTE`  WHERE 1
899 row inserted Query took 0.4357 - 0.4506 sec
```

**With IGNORE** (899 rows)
**Total time:  0.4090 - 0.4788 sec**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `LOCAL` SELECT * FROM `REMOTE`  WHERE 1
1 row inserted. Inserted Query took 0.4090 - 0.4788 sec
```

**Then I tried this Routine**
**Total time:  0.0006 - 0.0010**

```
$results = mysqli_query("SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `LOCAL` WHERE 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM);
$max = $row[0];
@mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `LOCAL` SELECT * FROM `id` FROM `REMOTE` WHERE `id` > $max");
```

Both the SELECT MAX and the INSERT WHERE `id` > $max took between 0.0003 - 0.0005 sec, (1 row inserted. Query took 0.0003 - 0.0005 sec)

I would delete the last row in the local table before running this routine.